# What is included in the death counter?

Tags: zelda-link-to-the-past

When you complete Zelda: A Link to the Past, you are presented with a variety of statistics about your playthrough, including how many times you died.

If you die and are resurrected by a faerie, does this still count as a death?

Do any other actions count as death?

Comment: Why would someone down vote this! I never even thought of it, but I'm pretty sure no because I've beaten the game with very low death counts and have used many faries

Comment: @Jeff Tooltip for downvote: "This question does not show any research effort..."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you die and are resurrected by a faerie, this does not count as a death and is not included in the death counter at the end, but saving and quitting does.

Comment: Wow, saving and quitting counts as a death? This explains why I've never had a death count below 10...

Comment: The GBA version was updated so that Saving and Quitting doesn't count towards the death counter.  Then again, it wasn't until Link's Awakening that the death counter actually did anything.